# SQL : Limit the results of one table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, limit

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT 
    c.nom AS race_name, 
    r.nom_coureur AS player_name, 
    r.prenom_coureur AS player_name_first
FROM pourvelobsx.calendrier AS c    
INNER JOIN pourvelobsx.resultat_autre AS r 
    ON r.identifiant_epreuve = c.identifiant
WHERE nom_etape = "final"
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The query returns 5 rows:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| race_name        | player_name | player_name_first |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Watashi wa Alex  | BARBAS      | Yoann             |
| Watashi wa Alex  | AHLSTRAND   | Jonas             |
| Watashi wa Alex  | ACEVEDO     | Janier Alexis     |
| Tour de La Baule | CHAVANEL    | Sylvain           |
| Tour de La Baule | SANCHEZ     | Samuel            |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I was wondering, how can I **limit the result of races** ("calendrier" table) and not the global row result ?

Like this:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| race_name        | player_name | player_name_first |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Watashi wa Alex  | BARBAS      | Yoann             |
| Watashi wa Alex  | AHLSTRAND   | Jonas             |
| Watashi wa Alex  | ACEVEDO     | Janier Alexis     |
| Tour de La Baule | CHAVANEL    | Sylvain           |
| Tour de La Baule | SANCHEZ     | Samuel            |
| Tour de La Groin | HELLO       | Calvin            |
| Tour de La Groin | ESTEBEZ     | Millo             |
| Tour de France   | SANCHEZ     | Samuel            |
| Tour de France   | SICKED      | Alex              |
| Tour d'Espagne   | VILLIOD     | Fred              |
| Tour d'Espagne   | CRACHER     | Jordan            |
| Tour d'Espagne   | ELBANTI     | Maxime            |
| Tour d'Espagne   | BOKEDRON    | Yohan             |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

So I only have 5 races not limiting row. I tried `DISTINCT` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: So you want to display all the 5 races ?

Comment: Which MySQL version? (Didn't they add window functions just recently?)

Comment: what output do u want?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why is the post downvoted ? CookieMonster yes, Prateik it is in the post. @jarlh, last one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this

```
SELECT 
  c.nom AS race_name, 
  r.nom_coureur AS player_name, 
  r.prenom_coureur AS player_name_first
FROM pourvelobsx.calendrier AS c    
INNER JOIN pourvelobsx.resultat_autre AS r ON r.identifiant_epreuve = c.identifiant
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT c.nom
  FROM pourvelobsx.calendrier AS c   
  INNER JOIN pourvelobsx.resultat_autre AS r ON r.identifiant_epreuve = c.identifiant     
  WHERE nom_etape = "final"
  GROUP BY c.nom
  ORDER BY c.id DESC
  LIMIT 5
) t ON t.nom = c.nom
WHERE nom_etape = "final"
```

Comment: You can't use `LIMIT` in `WHERE col IN` subqueries. You need to join with the subquery.

Comment: It is working great, thanks, but why do I have to do two INNER JOIN ?

Comment: @Dinath the first join is between `calendrier` and `resultat_autre` and the second join is between `resultat_autre` and `t` subquery. PS: you are welcome :)

Comment: @RadimBača Oh, I understand! Pretty hard to... And what about performance ? Thanks again :)